# How to create a responsive page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive landing page that changes it's format for mobile devices. I have tried using both flex box and bootstrap's grid system to do this but I guess I'm doing something wrong. I want the three parts of the heading to occupy a separate line on mobile devices while all being on the same line for larger devices and the same for the three buttons. At the moment this is working when I simply minimize the window on my laptop but it is not working when I view the page on my mobile devices.

I also want the instagram button to stay centered at the bottom on all devices.

My html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RBM Makeup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="intro">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
            <h1> <span id="Rebecca"> Rebecca </span> <span id="Bermingham"> Bermingham </span> <span id="Maguire"> Maguire</span></h1>
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-right">Portfolio</a>
                <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">Contact</a>
                <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-left">About Me</a>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="instagram">
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram" id="fix"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

/*These are the general bits*/

```
:root{
    --maroon: #85144b;
    --fuchsia: #f012be;
    --purple: #b10dc9;
    --lime: #01ff70;
    --black: #000000;
    --white: #ffffff;
    --blue: #89cff0;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'milkshake';
    src:url(fonts/Milkshake.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'amble';
    src:url(fonts/Amble-Regular.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/**/

.intro{
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    background: url("images/eye.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    display: table;
    top: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.92;
}

.intro .inner{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}

.content h1{
    color: var(--blue);
    font-size: 350%;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: bold;
    font-family: milkshake;
    font-weight: 100;
}

#Rebecca{
    color: var(--purple);
}

#Bermingham{
    color: var(--lime);
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.container a{
    border-radius: 9px;
    color: var(--black);
    font-size: 135%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid var(--black) 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 20px 40px;
    font-family: amble;
    font-weight: 150;
    font-style: bold;
}

/*Hover effects for 3 buttons*/

/*Left Button*/

.hvr-sweep-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: var(--purple);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-right:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-right:active {
  color: var(--white);
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-right:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

/*Middle Button*/

.hvr-sweep-to-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: var(--lime);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active {
  color: var(--purple);
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

/* Right Button */

.hvr-sweep-to-left {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: var(--blue);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-left:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-left:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-left:active {
  color: var(--black);
}
.hvr-sweep-to-left:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-left:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-left:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

/*Instagram Icon*/

.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-content: center;
}

.fa:hover{
    opacity:0.7;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 95px; 
   height: 100px;
   left: 50%; 
   margin-left: calc(-95px / 2); // here
}
```

The current landing page can be viewed at www.rebeccabm.github.io . Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: please add a code snippet that's viewable on this site

Comment: I'm pretty new to this site, i thought the above two snippets of code are viewable?

Comment: First thing I can see is that you are missing `viewport` in your code. Please add following in `head` of your `HTML` document: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Hi Ronan, you can add snippets of code that executes on this site. This is most practical so other's can see the results immediately and can also offer their suggestions within the thread.

Comment: I added <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> to the head and it worked perfectly, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Each span should be set to `display:block;` in the particular media query used per break point. The example below should be placed in your CSS. Do note, it's best practice to start building with "Mobile First" in mind, or you'll have to reset the span for larger views.

```
/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  .intro span {display:block;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use bootstrap framework either use media query css

i.e. : 
For iPad
@media and(max-width:767px){

}

For iPhone or any small media devices :

@media and(max-width:480px){

}